# Getting data from a webpage table

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I know how to read content from a web page , but I am stuck to extract valid content from the page. i want to extract only tables that have some data content. and i have no table id. Like i want to get tables from below link...use c sharp

http://www.unece.org/cefact/locode/service/location.html

Comment: It sounds like you want to do something called "screen scraping."  You have user-formatted data and you need to pull strongly-typed data from it.  Since what you have is the HTML output from a web site, something like the HTML Agility Pack may be useful for parsing it and getting the data you need from it: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com

Answer (score 1):

In general, for parsing out data from HTML, you should use a purpose built HTML parser.

Two good options are:

- [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) - uses XPath / LINQ to query the parsed HTML
- [CsQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery) - uses jQuery like selector syntax to query the parsed HTML

The choice between the two should boil down to which query syntax you (and your team) are more comfortable with.